# Cannot calculate correctly a 2d array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, dynamic-programming

Well, i have this part of a program and i can't get the output i'm expecting no matter what i do. I used 8 'println' in a desperate try to find my mistake, but still can't figure out what i should do. Although i think the problem starts at the second value of *k .. k=1*.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      String path = args[0];
      BufferedReader br = null;
      String line;

       int count = 0;
       while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {

              if (count==0) {
                 int n = Integer.parseInt(line);
             }

            else if (count==1) {
                 int m = Integer.parseInt(line);
                 int Cost = new int[n][m];
                 int VMs = new int[m][m];
            }

           else if (count>=3 && count<n+3) { 
                   String[] Spliter = line.split("\\s+"); 
                   for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                 String str = Spliter[j];
                 int x = Integer.parseInt(str);
                 Cost[count-3][j] = x;
                   }
           }

           else if (count>=n+4 && count<=n+4+m) {
                   String[] Spliter = line.split("\\s+");
                   for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
                       String str = Spliter[k];
                       int x = Integer.parseInt(str);
                       Vms[count-n-4][k] = x; 
                    }
           }

           count++;
         }

           int[][] NewCost = new int[n][m];
                for (int w = 0; w<m; w++){
                    NewCost[0][w]=Cost[0][w];
           }

           for (int i = 1; i<n; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j<m; j++){
                   int a = 10000;

                   for (int k = 0; k<m; k++){
                       y = Cost[i-1][k] + Cost[i][j] + Vms[k][j];

                       if (y < a) {
                          NewCost[i][j] = y;
                          a = y;
                       }
                   }
                }
            }

           for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
               for (int j = 0; j<m; j++) {
                 System.out.print(NewCost[i][j] + " ");
               }
                  System.out.print("\n");
         }
      }
```

for the input below  (the **<--** are mine explanations and are not inlcuded in the input text)

```
4     <--that's my n
3     <--that's my m

5 6 3
7 8 5    <--that's the *Cost* array
7 8 3
2 7 6

0 7 2
7 0 2    <--that's the *VMs* array
2 2 0
```

i should get something like this

```
5 6 3 
12 13 8     <-- *NewCost* array
17 18 11
15 20 17
```

but istead i get this

```
5 6 3 
12 13 8
14 15 8
7 12 9
```

examples of calculations:

```
NewCost[0][j] = Cost[0][j]     <-- this must be true in every possible input. 
To be specific, in this example we want the first row NewCost[0][j] = {5 , 6 , 3}

NewCost[1][0] = min(X1,X2,X3) = min(12,20,12) = 12
X1=Cost[0][0]+Cost[1][0]+VMs[0][0] = 5+7+0 = 12
X2=Cost[0][1]+Cost[1][0]+VMs[1][0] = 6+7+7 = 20
X3=Cost[0][2]+Cost[1][0]+VMs[2][0] = 3+7+2 = 12

NewCost[1][1] = min(Y1,Y2,Y3) = min(20,14,13) = 13
Y1=Cost[0][0]+Cost[1][1]+VMs[0][1] = 5+8+7 = 20
Y2=Cost[0][1]+Cost[1][1]+VMs[1][1] = 6+8+0 = 14
Y3=Cost[0][2]+Cost[1][1]+VMs[2][1] = 3+8+2 = 13

NewCost[1][2] = min(Z1,Z2,Z3) = min(12,13,8) = 8
Z1=Cost[0][0]+Cost[1][2]+VMs[0][2] = 5+5+2 = 12
Z2=Cost[0][1]+Cost[1][2]+VMs[1][2] = 6+5+2 = 13
Z3=Cost[0][2]+Cost[1][2]+VMs[2][2] = 3+5+0 = 8

So the second row will be NewCost[1][j] = {12 , 13 , 8}

NewCost[2][0] = min(X1,X2,X3) = min(19,27,17) = 17
X1=Cost[1][0]+Cost[2][0]+VMs[0][0] = 12+7+0 = 19
X2=Cost[1][1]+Cost[2][0]+VMs[1][0] = 13+7+7 = 27
X3=Cost[1][2]+Cost[2][0]+VMs[2][0] = 8+7+2 = 17

NewCost[2][1] = min(Y1,Y2,Y3) = min(27,21,18) = 18
Y1=Cost[1][0]+Cost[2][1]+VMs[0][1] = 12+8+7 = 27
Y2=Cost[1][1]+Cost[2][1]+VMs[1][1] = 13+8+0 = 21
Y3=Cost[1][2]+Cost[2][1]+VMs[2][1] = 8+8+2 = 18

NewCost[2][2] = min(Z1,Z2,Z3) = min(17,18,11) = 11
Z1=Cost[1][0]+Cost[2][2]+VMs[0][2] = 12+3+2 = 17
Z2=Cost[1][1]+Cost[2][2]+VMs[1][2] = 13+3+2 = 18
Z3=Cost[1][2]+Cost[2][2]+VMs[2][2] = 8+3+0 = 11

So the third row will be NewCost[2][j] = {17 , 18 , 11}

NewCost[3][0] = min(X1,X2,X3) = min(19,27,15) = 15
X1=Cost[2][0]+Cost[3][0]+VMs[0][0] = 17+2+0 = 19
X2=Cost[2][1]+Cost[3][0]+VMs[1][0] = 18+2+7 = 27
X3=Cost[2][2]+Cost[3][0]+VMs[2][0] = 11+2+2 = 15

NewCost[3][1] = min(Y1,Y2,Y3) = min(31,25,20) = 20
Y1=Cost[2][0]+Cost[3][1]+VMs[0][1] = 17+7+7 = 31
Y2=Cost[2][1]+Cost[3][1]+VMs[1][1] = 18+7+0 = 25
Y3=Cost[2][2]+Cost[3][1]+VMs[2][1] = 11+7+2 = 20

NewCost[3][2] = min(Z1,Z2,Z3) = min(25,26,17) = 17
Z1=Cost[2][0]+Cost[3][2]+VMs[0][2] = 17+6+2 = 25
Z2=Cost[2][1]+Cost[3][2]+VMs[1][2] = 18+6+2 = 26
Z3=Cost[2][2]+Cost[3][2]+VMs[2][2] = 11+6+0 = 17

So the forth row will be NewCost[3][j] = {15 , 20 , 17}
```

Comment: Please follow [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html): `firstWordLowerCaseVariable`, `FirstWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()` and `ALL_WORDS_UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT` and use them consistently, so the code becomes more readable for you and us.

Comment: Well i think its ok now. Though i'm a starter here and in java in general so forgive me if i still haven't got what you meant and didn't fix it properly.

Comment: Could you read [mcve] and post one? We're missing the `main` and declaration of `Cost` and `VMs` as well.

Comment: oh sorry, i thought it would make it too big to read, i'll fix it right away

Comment: As long as it meets the MCVE rules and that you post a specific question, your question would be good. :)

Comment: I posted the whole program but i think i messed up with some spaces etc, if you think i need to "cut out" some things they re not in use, tell me to do so. And thanks for the advice so far :)

Comment: I think I fixed some of the spacing issues.

Comment: Thanks for the help @mackycheese21! Now i hope someone helps me with the problem in this code :/

Comment: The program is supposed to be doing matrix multiplication? Is that the purpose?

Comment: No, not at all. It has to make some additions between lines i and i-1 (from Cost array) combined with the VMs array and finally find the minimum value of the adds. It will be more helpfull to see the last part of the ''question box''

Comment: When replying to someone, use `@username` so that they get notified, for example: @mackycheese21 (The `@` is important).

Comment: Could you explain a little better how the calculations are done? Using your array indexes and numbers? Or a draw / diagram. As it's not clear

Comment: Like what would your algorithm be to calculate `NewCost[x][y]`?  A single example is not helpful.

Comment: @Frakcool and @mackycheese21 i added the calculations of whole 2nd row of `NewCost[][]`. If you want i can write as well the calculations of the rest 2 rows.

Comment: What would be most helpful is an explanation of how you intend to calculate one of the values that is _not_ currently being calculated correctly, that is, one of the bottom two rows.  It's not obvious what math you intend to be done there.

Comment: As said above by @mackycheese21 and I, create a sample WITH NUMBERS (preferred an image) of the actual calculations. Be very detailed as I'm not sure how it's all done. Go through each of the numbers if possible.

Comment: @Frakcool finally i'm done! I think the calculations are understandable now.

Comment: @ojchase sorry for not replying sooner, just saw your comment. I added all calculations in details :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We still don't really understand the problem you're trying to solve, but it appears from your example calculations that the first value you wish to include in your additions is the optimized value from the previous iteration of the outermost loop.  Your problem is that you've saved that previous iteration only in `NewCost` but are only reading values from `Cost`.

For `NewCost[2][0]` you calculated `X3=Cost[1][2]+Cost[2][0]+VMs[2][0] = 8+7+2 = 17`, which is inaccurate.  `Cost[1][2]` is 5, not 8, as it's coming from the original `Cost` array.  If you're wanting 8 to be retrieved from the previous iteration, you're going to need to look it up from the `NewCost` array where you saved that result.

This is the point of dynamic programming, to use optimal values you've calculated recently in your next round of calculations.  But it only works if you use your recent calculations!

Try changing

```
y = Cost[i-1][k] + Cost[i][j] + Vms[k][j];
```

to

```
y = NewCost[i-1][k] + Cost[i][j] + Vms[k][j];
```

Comment: Oh man!! i had the answer before my eyes and couldn't think of it. First of all thanks a lot all of you for your help! Well the program is like a virtual display of N jobs running on M machines and i want to find the minimun cost of a job running in each machine type. The *NxM* array represents the cost of a job to run in each machine and the *MxM* array represents the cost of switching machine type. I don't think that helps, as my english are not the best so i really hope you understood somehow what the program is about. Again thanks a lot!!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  That actually does help clarify the problem and would make a good edit to the question, in case any other more thorough answers come in.  If this answer or any future better ones solved your issue, please mark one as accepted.

Comment: didn't know i had to mark. i marked your solution cause it worked perfectly fine!